# Cairo delayed a paint at the call of cairo_push_gorup()

Tags: webkit, cairo

At the time of adding a separate surface for transparency layer it yields slowness. So i have added as cairo_clip() and cairo_set_paint_alpha() but some transparency functionality has not been happened. Whether there has alternative solution to perform a better user response by resolving this issue.

Comment: Sorry, but I fail to understand the question here. E.g., there is no function called cairo_set_paint_alpha(). Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: Yeah #Uli Schlachter. We are using the webkit and connected with cairo backend openGL. And we have faced a slowness issue while applying transparency using cairo_push_group() because temporary surface is created and maintained upto painting function happen. so browser consumes more time to paint. Here i have fixed using the cairo_clip(context) & cairo_paint_with_alpha(context,opacity) but there was much misbehavior while using this. So i need to fix it as like cairo_push_group() by avoiding the slowness.

Comment: Okay... then, my personal answer to your question would be: I do not know.